# After update Ionic all the pages not seen

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Today I updated my `Ionic` to the **latest version** and when I reloaded my app magically stopped working, the `menu` does work but no `route` works and much less lets see the `tabs`, I studied and there is a class *** `ion-page-invisible` *** that appears out of nowhere and has an `opacity property: 0`, try downloading the `Ionic version` and still not working, any ideas?

**Version of proyect**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 5.4.9 (C:\Users\FOOX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 4.11.7

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.3.0
   @capacitor/core : 1.3.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
```

**Page example**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { IonButton, IonSlides, IonSlide, IonContent } from '@ionic/react';
    import Agenda from './agenda.png';
    import './Controller.css';


    /**
     * Para usar history dentro de un componente inteligente o del tipo class, se necesita:
     * 1. Crear la clase
     * 2. importar import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
     * 3. extenderla a React.Component y asociar a <RouteComponentProps>
     * 4. al exportar la clase poner export default withRouter(nameComponent)
     */

    class Controller extends Component{
      render() {

        return (
          <IonPage>
           <IonContent>
            <IonSlides>
              <IonSlide>
                <img src={Agenda} alt="imageUno" className="imageSlides" />
              </IonSlide>

              <IonSlide>
                Contactanos: 12312312312
                email: asdads@assdassd.com
                password: 12312312312
                </IonSlide>

            </IonSlides>

            <IonButton expand="block" mode="ios" color="dark" routerDirection="forward" routerLink="/Login">
              Ingresar
              </IonButton>

            <IonButton expand="block" mode="ios" color="dark" routerDirection="forward" routerLink="/LoginClient">
              Ingresar como Cliente
              </IonButton>

            <IonButton expand="block" mode="ios" color="light" routerDirection="forward" routerLink="/CreateAccount">
              Crear Cuenta
              </IonButton>
            <IonContent/>
          </IonPage>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Controller;
```

**Update -> Add code of App.tsx and routes.tsx**

***App.tsx (  where i put the routes )***

```
  render() {
    return (
      <IonApp>
        <IonReactRouter>
        <Menu isLogged={this.state.isLoged} type={this.state.userData.type} />
          <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
            <Routes isLoged={this.state.isLoged} id={this.state.id} userData={this.state.userData} />
          </IonSplitPane>
        </IonReactRouter>
      </IonApp>
    );
  }
```

***Routes***

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component<props>{
  render() {
    return (
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main" contextMenu="main">

        <Route exact path="/Controller" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Redirect to="/Home" />
            : <Controller />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/Login" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Redirect to="/Controller" />
            : <Login />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/CreateAccount" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Redirect to="/Home" />
            : <CreateAccount />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/Home" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Home id={this.props.id} type={this.props.userData.type} />
            : <Redirect to="/Login" />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/AdminCompanies" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <AdminCompanies />
            : <Redirect to="/Login" />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/FinancialState" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <ControllerUploadFiles id={this.props.id} targetDb="financial_state" title="Estados Financieros" />
            : <Redirect to="/Login" />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/Rut" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <ControllerUploadFiles id={this.props.id} targetDb="register_unique_tribute" title="Registro Unico Tributario" />
            : <Redirect to="/Login" />
        )} />

        <Route exact path="/Settings" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Settings id={this.props.id} accountData={this.props.userData} />
            : <Redirect to="/Login" />
        )} />

        {/* Ingreso de la cuenta del tipo cliente */}
        <Route exact path="/LoginClient" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Redirect to="/Controller" />
            : <LoginClient />
        )} />

        {/* RUTAS DE LOS CLIENTES */}
        <Route exact path="/MyAccountans" render={() => (
          this.props.isLoged
            ? <Redirect to="/Home" />
            : <MyAccountants id={this.props.id} />
        )} />

        <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/Controller" />} />

      </IonRouterOutlet>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: need to see more code? also the router code

Comment: Yes, i upload an new update